# Another problem with a proof in "Topics in Algebra" by Herstein- every element in R can be written as a finite product of prime numbers.

Tags: ring-theory

On pg. 146 of the second edition, it says let $a=bc$, where $a,b,c\in R$. $R$ is a Euclidean ring. 
If $d:R\to Z$, then if $b$ is a unit, $d(a)=d(c)$ [$d(a)=d(b)$ if $c$ is a unit]. If neither $b$ nor $c$ are units, $d(b)$ and $d(c)$ are $<d(a)=d(bc)$.

The proof says that assume all elements $d(x)<d(a)$ can be written as the finite product of prime elements. Then $b$ and $c$ can also be written as that.

Hence $a$, being equal to $bc$ can also be written as the finite product of finite elements.

**This is fine. But I don't understand how this proves ALL the elements of the ring can be written in this form. For example, how does this prove that $b+c$ can be written in this form.**

Comment: The induction hypothesis is that any $x$ such that $d(x)\lt d(a)$ is a product of a finite number of primes. The conclusion is that $a$ is a finite product of primes. If $a$ is a prime we are finished. Else $a=bc$ for some $b$, $c$, neither of them a unit. But then $d(b)\lt d(a)$, and $d(b)\lt d(a)$. So $b$ and $c$ are, by the induction hypothesis, a product of primes.

Comment: Your notation may be part of the source of confusion. The induction hypothesis in the proof you quote says that if $d(x)\lt d(a)$, then $x$ (not $d(x)$) is a product of primes. It does not say that $d(b)$ and $d(c)$ can b written like that, it says $b$ and $c$ can be written like that.

Comment: Thanks. The relevant edits have been made. And you're right. That does prove that bc will be a product of primes. But does it prove _all_ elements of the ring can be represented as products of primes? For example, does it prove that $b+c$ can be represented as a product of primes? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The element $b+c$ has a "size" $d(b+c)$ assigned to it. Say it is large, like $500$. In $500$ steps, our induction process will reach it.

Comment: @AndréNicolas- I don't understand. There is no "if it is true for $t_{n}$, it is also true for $t_{n+1}$" step here. It will not reach there in 500 steps! I don't think the induction statement was even used here.

Comment: @Ayush: There is indeed such a step here. The induction hypothesis $P(n)$ is that if $d(a)<n$, then $a$ can be written as a finite product of primes. The induction step, which appears in your question, consists in assuming that $d(a)=n$ and showing that $a$ can be written as a finite product of primes. This shows that $P(n+1)$ is true: if $d(a)<n+1$, then $a$ can be written as a finite product of primes. It now follows by induction that $P(n)$ is true for all $n$, which is what you were trying to prove.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott- Yes there is thanks a lot! And to Andre too! I should've understood this much earlier, but was moving in circles based on a wrong assumption.

Comment: @Ayush: You’re welcome!